# Statically load a QML Component without instantiating it

Tags: components, qml, qt5, qtquick2

As I understand it, a QML `Component` is like a kind of like a class in C++. It contains the definition of a QML object but isn't an instance of it. You can create a `Component` in these ways:

1. Creating a `.qml` file with the component name as its filename.
2. Define it inline with the `Component { }` syntax.

However these are actually two different things. The second one is more like a factory because you can do things like:

```
Component {
    id: factory
    Rectangle { width: 100; height:100; color: "red }
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    var rect1 = factory.createObject(parent);
}
```

Whereas with the separate file you need to first load it into a factory like this:

```
    var factory = Qt.createComponent("RedRectangle.qml")
    var rect1 = factory.createObject(parent);
```

I'm only concerned with dynamic object creation, so this is not an option:

```
RedRectangle {
    id: rect1
}
```

My question is: is there a way to create the objects dynamically, without having to create the Component factory dynamically too, and without having to specify the Component inline. I.e. I want the first example, but where the `Rectangle` is specified in another file.

I want this:

```
Component {
    id: factory
    url: "RedRectangle.qml"
}
Component.onCompleted: {
    var rect1 = factory.createObject(parent);
}
```

Sadly that doesn't work. I also tried this:

```
Component {
    id: factory
}
Component.onCompleted: factory.loadUrl("RedRectangle.qml");
```

But it doesn't work either. Am I being stupid or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some encapsulation:

Fact.qml (for some reason it doesn't let me name it Factory)

```
QtObject {
    property string url
    readonly property Component component : Qt.createComponent(url)
    function get() { return component }
    function load(url) { return Qt.createComponent(url) }
}
```

usage:

```
Fact {
    id: f
    url: "RedRect.qml"
}

StackView {
    id: stack
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    stack.push(f.component) // redrect
    f.url = "BlueRect.qml"
    stack.push(f.get()) // bluerect, redundant but shorter
    stack.push(f.load("GreenRect.qml")) // greenrect, f.component is still bluerect
}
```

It will only load the component when its `component` property is referenced and you can change the url to load other components with the same `Fact` instance. Also the auxiliary `load()` method, which returns a component without actually changing the one potentially cached.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is not too bad, though I still think `Component` should support specifying a url directly.

Here is my solution:

```
property var factory: Qt.createComponent("RedRectangle.qml")
```

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I felt like Qt should have support for a certain feature or an existing feature should work in a different way, I'd be a millionaire. Just because it is a big framework doesn't mean it is complete, in fact in many ways it is far from that. Just be glad the solution is so straightforward. I've lost the count of how many times I had to reinvent wheels with Qt.